# Exception: Parameter validation failed:

Tags: python, lambda

I have tried to set rotation parameter in VideoSelector the below code.
but I am getting like this.

> Exception: Parameter validation failed:
>   Unknown parameter in Settings.Inputs[0].VideoSelector: "Rotate", must be one of: ColorSpace, ColorSpaceUsage, Hdr10Metadata, Pid, ProgramNumber

```
"VideoSelector": {
    "ColorSpace": "FOLLOW",
    "Pid": 123,
    "ProgramNumber": 123,
    "Rotate": "DEGREE_0"
}
```

Comment: What library is this? Also, what does this have to do with `lambda`?

Comment: Here i am using boto3 to create media converter job. This lambda trigger whenever s3 bucket have a new video. This creates a media converter job.

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: @Robert
Exception: Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in Settings.Inputs[0].VideoSelector: "Rotate", must be one of: ColorSpace, ColorSpaceUsage, Hdr10Metadata, Pid, ProgramNumber. 

I am getting error message like this in lambda function. I don't know which message you are asking. kindly explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem here is the aws-sdk version used by the python lambda function is not latest.  The just added rotate option months ago, and is now showing up in the options being returned to you.

If I knew how to make the python lambda function use the latest version I would tell you.  Its a mystery to me right now.